# Fetching few sorted records from huge table

Tags: sql, nosql, scalability

Let's pretend I have a huge website and a huge table (with some million entries table) with a few columns ("ID", "AuthorID", "Message", "Time" for example) to contain twitter-like messages.

I want to execute the following simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM HugeTable ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1,10;
```

This query shall be executed a lot of times (tens per second). How do I make sure that this query is very fast?

I tought memcached could have been a solution, but new posts are added very quickly, and using memcached I would provide "old" messages to users.

Assume that I have only one mysql server, and it is so good that it can handle all the traffic.

My problem is that the server should take the whole table, sorting that (huge bottleneck here), and then take only the first 10. So, what is the best optimization that I could do? Partitioning maybe? Also, inside the table, newer posts are put on the bottom, so it's safe to assume that a new post will have "ID" and "Time" >= than the previous.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I'm not an expert of MySql (even though I know the basis), and I have no clue about NoSql methods. If you believe NoSql is the way to suffice my task, then I'm open to learn using something new :)

Answer (score 3):

As you surmise, caching is the way to go. Either by creating a parallel table with the ten records you want in it (each time you do an insert, you remove the oldest one), or by doing the same thing further up the stack in memory. It's about how you manage what's in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

No an answer to your question, but as an answer to your problem. I wouldn't use a query but would use a websocket solution to push posts to clients when they arrive. Connected clients would always receive the latest post when they arrive and a websockets solution should have less overhead.

Comment: and what about when you have just got to the home and need to load the latest posts? You have to wait that someone posts to actually see something...

Comment: If posts are added very quickly that should not be a problem, but if you want to show the 10 latest posts first I would use the caching as suggested by podiluska.